# Dark mode checkbox should be saved in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement a dark mode - light mode switcher on my website. I don't really know anything about JS but I played around with the code snippets I found online and put together something that kind of works.

What I have so far:
- I have two sets of colors in CSS that I can switch between with a checkbox in the navbar.
- I also found out how I can store a checkbox's state locally, so if I turn on the dark mode and then navigate to another page, the checkbox is still checked.

The problem is that every time I navigate to another page, the checkbox gets unchecked first and then it realises that it has to be checked and it checks itself automatically. But it takes time, there's even an animation which is kind of annoying because if I check it on a page, I want it to be checked by default on all the other pages until I turn it off.

Here's a video that explains it better: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y48yh1h1bGM6abrthVmtUD8azVuDG4yE/view?usp=sharing

Any help would be appreciated since I really don't know what's going on here :D

```
// DARK MODE SWITCHER
var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[name=mode]');

checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if(this.checked) {
    trans()
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark')
  } else {
    trans()
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light')
  }
})

let trans = () => {
  document.documentElement.classList.add('transition');
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove('transition');
  }, 1000)
}


// SAVE DARK MODE CHECKBOX STATE IN LOCAL STORAGE

var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {},
$checkboxes = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");

$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
  $checkboxes.each(function(){
    checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
  });

  localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));
});

// On page load
$.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
  $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
});
```

Comment: i have an idea, can you edit edit your post with a snippet (html + js) ?

Comment: @SimonDehaut of course. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zsoltszilvai/kf8gLoab/9/

Comment: while this, i made my own, https://jsfiddle.net/vkoeq9Lf/4/ , it's your code and it works

Comment: @SimonDehaut thanks, I took a look at it but it still changes the colors back to the light theme on page refresh: https://jsfiddle.net/zsoltszilvai/jngmkLw6/5/

Comment: ok i have the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the jsfiddle solution :

https://jsfiddle.net/zhbo40ma/

you need to set your theme at page load :

```
$.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
  $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
  if($('#'+key).attr('name') == 'mode') {
    if(value) {
        trans();
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark')
    }
    else {
        trans();
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light')
    }
  }
});
```

don't forget to write your `trans()` function before your page load function cause you declare it with a `let`

Comment: Nice! It does solve the second problem completely!! Thanks a lot!!
Now my only problem is this flickering:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11AIaPUFqaRheH3XVb7bY_eXqFUmSxA4K/view?usp=sharing
Do you have any tips on how to get rid of that? 

Comment: i suggest you rewrite your code cause it's not quiet maintenable : you should completly separate the code for the links (works ...) from the code for the theme mode. I think flickering is due to the two declartion of click event handler (one in vallina JS and one in jquery) .

actually your 'page load' function check state of more than just the dark mode checkbox